# How to check other user's input command or related command history log in Red hat 7.5

Tags: rhel, command-history

I find sometimes I can't see other user's input command when other user logins Linux system at same time:

**Do you know how to see such input in below Red-hat 7.5 system?
Also does anyone know how to see such input command history for other users?**

-------------- Related detail ------------------------

```
[appuser@ip-10-1-X-XX ~]$ w
 15:02:01 up  6:41,  2 users,  load average: 0.20, 0.07, 0.06
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
rouser   pts/0    ip-10-1-1-XX.cn- 10:11    3:23m  0.00s  0.00s tail -f lykos-reports.log
appuser  pts/1    ip-10-1-1-XX.cn- 14:56    1.00s  0.00s  0.00s w
You have mail in /var/spool/mail/appuser


[appuser@ip-10-1-1-239 ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo)
```

Thanks

Comment: When you say that _"sometimes I can't see other user's input command"_, does it mean that sonetimes you **can**? Also, when you're talking about "input commands", I assume you just mean the history of the commands they executed in their shells?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct.

Comment: And regarding the first half of my comment, about _"sometimes"_ you can't see their history? How do you see their history in the times you **can**?

Comment: Hi Aviro,
Thanks for replying.
Regarding " How do you see their history in the times you can? "

I tried like below to see what did someone input :

[appuser@ip-172-X-X-X-X ~]$ history 50